# Using Tint and Background Color for NavigationBar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uibackgroundcolor, bartintcolor

I have to color the navigation bar for a view in swift, but it's becoming difficult to do with the tint altering the color. The bottom color within the view is the final result I need, but setting that in the viewDidLoad causes it  to come out different. Any direction anyone can point me in?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...

    switch category {
    case "Corn Management":
        // color to be determined
        break
    case "Soybean Management":
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 153.0/255.0, green: 50.0/255.0, blue: 30.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    self.title = category
}
```

image: http://tinypic.com/r/2yo36tw/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it comes different because the navigationbar is translucent. You need to apply the formula from that link:
http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/bar-color-calculator-for-ios7-and-ios8/
Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent. Unfortunately, our designs call for one of those values to be under 40, but that's much better than what we had. Thanks!

Comment: If it's still actual you can also try [BarTintColorOptimizer tool](https://github.com/IvanRublev/BarTintColorOptimizer) to get the optimized navigation bar's color. 

For color from the question the optimized one is #880f00 or `UIColor(red:0.537096, green:0.060848, blue:0.002844, alpha:1.0)`. Use it instead of original color as `barTintColor` property value and get the correct appearance of the navigation bar.